# jpa query doesn't seem to resolve enum value correctly and always returns empty list

Tags: java, mysql, jpa, persistence, enumeration

I'm writing a very simple query which only queries for Foo objects with a given status, but the result I get is always an empty list, but I really have no idea what was wrong with my code.

My `findByStatus` method looks like this:

```
public List<Foo> findByStatus(final Status status, final int startIndex, final int maxRows)
{
    List<Foo> foos= getJpaTemplate().executeFind(new JpaCallback()
    {
        @Override
        public Object doInJpa(EntityManager entityManager) throws PersistenceException
        {
            Query q = entityManager.createQuery("SELECT f FROM Foo f WHERE f.status = :status", Foo.class);
            q.setParameter("status", status);    //This will not automatically resolve???
            q.setFirstResult(startIndex).setMaxResults(maxRows);
            return q.getResultList();
        }
    });

    return foos == null ? Collections.EMPTY_LIST : foos;
}
```

HOWEVER, if I (1) take out the Foo.class (the second param in `entityManager.createQuery` and (2) do `q.setParameter("status", status.name())` instead, then I'll get the correct result list.

Does anyone know what's wrong here?

By the way, my Foo class that looks like this:

```
public class Foo
{
  @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING) @Column(nullable=false, columnDefinition = "VARCHAR(10) DEFAULT 'ON'")
  private Status status= Status.ON;

  //other fields
}
```

And status looks like this

```
public enum Status
{
  ON("ON"),
  OFF("OFF"),
  UNKNOWN("UNKNOWN");

  private String status;

  private Status(String status)
  {
     this.status = status;
  }

  public String getStatus()
  {
     return status;
  }
}
```

So looks like hibernate bind my enum value to some VARBINARY, which is weird:

```
2013-12-27 11:38:35,341 TRACE [org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder]  - <binding parameter [1] as [VARBINARY] - ON>
```

Comment: Please turn on SQL statement logging for your JPA provider and let us know what the generated SQL looks like.

Comment: Ah that's one more question I wanted to ask and sorry if I seem obtuse here, but how do I turn that on? I've been messing with my debugger trying to get the generated query without much success.

Comment: That's provider-dependent. If you're using Hibernate, turn up logging for `org.hibernate.SQL` in your logger to debug.

Comment: I found some instruction on hibernate site, but I don't think I have access to that low level of configs in this project. Things seem to be   pretty much so-called "well encapsulated." 

are there other ways to see the generated query?

Comment: No, that's it. You should learn how to work with your logging system. Both log4j and logback make it easy to change the log levels of loggers by just changing a config file in your top-level project.

Comment: Ok I found org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl and turned that on, that's the only that seems closest to what I need. I tried looked for `org.hibernate.SQL` but it's nowhere to be found among the log4j packages

Comment: Oops never mind. Ok found it!

Comment: But either way, the sql doesn't say much: `
2013-12-27 11:29:24,976 DEBUG [org.hibernate.SQL]  - <select fo0_.id as id68_, fo0_.version as version68_, fo0_.status as status68_ from Foo fo0_ where status=?>`

Comment: Please post the Hibernate version and your DB's exported DDL for this table.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem in one specific application.

The root cause in that hibernate is ignoring the @Enumerated annotion and always passing to the sql the enum as
VARBINARY